# Resources for learning to output xml from rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I would like to use rails to output xml on a request from a client (Android device). I have gleaned from web searches that .builder.xml files are the way to go for this, but I cannot find a single tutorial or guide to get me started that is newer that 2006.. does anyone know of a good resource for xml and rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to look at the official XML Builder homepage and follow/try the examples there: http://builder.rubyforge.org/

You can use XML Builder in both your controller or in your views, the code is the same. However, inside an .builder view you already have access to a builder instance via the "xml" variable. See: http://danengle.us/2009/05/generating-custom-xml-for-your-rails-app/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/2-how-to-create-a-dynamic-sitemap-using-ruby-on-rails) about XML Builder.

I also highly recommend you to [use Nokogiri](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk/browse_thread/thread/3ba1077d3e6e3374/da17c8a9bd293179?pli=1) to generate XML.